# How does shopware set values for line items

Tags: symfony, shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

I'm trying to figure which logic is used to set line item values for shopware to solve the following problem, I have injected a dynamic form in the PDP and created a promise based function that creates a serializable JSON object from the filled form data, I would like to attach this JSON object to the cart items conditionally.
So... Where can I find the logic responsible for resolving cart items addition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the data in the Payload by subscribing the `LineItemAddedEvent`.
As [shown here in the forum](https://forum.shopware.com/t/how-can-we-set-custom-fields-per-cart-line-item/62122/5).

For this to work, you have to send the additional data in the same request which is sending the cart-addition to the server to be able to fetch the data from the `Request` you can inject to the subscriber.

Comment: I thought about subscribing to the `('beforeFormSubmit', formData);` add to cart action, resolving the promise(I have registered it on the window object) then attach it to `formData.customProp` and override the /add action controller

Comment: the answer found in the form mentions that the payload is stored in the cart table, but as I went through the shopware developer training it's mentioned that it's stored in a session token

Comment: The session token refers to a session stored on the server, which references to the cart t able, I believe